# RequireJS object not defined

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I keep getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
```

The first time:

```
<script>
    require(['core/controller']);
</script>
```

The secondoccurrence is:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery": [
            "jquery"
        ],
        'bootstrap': [
            'bootstrap'
        ],
        'kendo': [
            'kendo'
        ],
        handlebars: 'handlebars'
    },
    shim: {
        "bootstrap": {
            deps :["jquery"]
        },
        "kendo": {
            deps: ["jquery"]
        }
    }
})

define('config', function (require) {
    'use strict';

    var module = require('module');

    return module.config ? module.config() : {};
});

define('events', ['core/mini-events'], function(EventEmitter){

    var events = new EventEmitter();

    return events;

});
```

In my header I have:

```
<script data-main="/js/main.js" src="http://mbms.com/js/requirejs.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you're running this locally on your machine, then use relative paths instead of absolute path for `require.js`. Change your src to `/js/requirejs.js`

Answer (score 1):

```
<script data-main="/js/main.js" src="http://mbms.com/js/requirejs.js"></script>
```

The absolute URL that you mentioned in your script's `src` doesn't exist. As the host and the file do not exist, `requirejs.js` is not downloaded and any attempt to use `require` API will give you the error that you're getting now. As you're running this locally, I suggest you change your src like below

```
<script data-main="/js/main.js" src="/js/requirejs.js"></script>
```

As long as there's a `js` folder with `requirejs.js` file under your project root folder, then this change should work :)

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT for clarity]
I tried the URL referenced in the script tag just now and it's not present. Check your debugger's Network console and you'll see the 404. Perhaps you meant:

http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.16/minified/require.js

Comment: What url? thats just a local site on my machine.

Comment: http://mbms.com/js/requirejs.js is not a URL? If you're overriding the public DNS for mbms.com, explain that in the question.